# JavaScript addEventListeners not running from script file for web app

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I have been through many of the other threads about non-functioning EventListeners in JavaScript, but it seems that no one has had the problem I currently am.

I have a series of buttons that I want to trigger some forms on my web page to be displayed on click. I have written a series of statements to add eventListeners to the buttons (selected by element ID), which calls a function that switches the display of the forms to flex (the display attribute of the forms is set to none in an external css file) on click (selected by class).

Statements to add eventListeners:

```
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector('.login-menu').style.display="flex";
});

document.getElementById("register").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector('.reg-menu').style.display="flex";
});

document.getElementById("addTopic").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector('.topic-form-container').style.display="flex";
});

document.getElementById("claim-reply-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector('.reply-to-claimform-container').style.display="flex";
});

document.getElementById("reply-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector('.reply-to-reply-form-container').style.display="flex";
});

document.getElementById("addClaim").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector('.claim-form-container').style.display="flex";
});
```

The first two buttons (login and register), which are buttons for the page's nav-bar are working fine.
For some reason the other eventListeners are not working, however. I have also run the statements through the console in the developer window, and when I do this it adds the eventListener and the buttons work fine. The script is linked right before the  tag closes, so it isn't the case that script is loading before the HTML elements.

Here are the HTML forms that are not appearing, for brevity's sake.

```
<div id='topic-form' class='topic-form-container'>
    <form method='POST' id='topic-form' action='/'>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type='text' 
        id='topic-title'
        name='title'
        size="35 rem"
        placeholder='Enter Topic Title: 200 characters or less'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add a topic</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="claim-form" class="claim-form-container">
    <form method='POST' id='claim-form' action='/post_claim'>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type='text'
        id='claim-title'
        name='title'
        size='35 rem'
        placeholder='Enter Claim Title: 200 characters or less'>
        <label for='text-body'>Text Body</label>
        <textarea name='text' rows='4' cols='50' placeholder='Enter description: 500 characters or less'></textarea>
        
        <label for='relation'>Select relation:</label>
        <select name='relation' id='claim-relation'>
            <option value='opposed'>Opposed</option>
            <option value='equivalent'>Equivalent</option>
            <option value='none'>None</option>
        </select>
        
        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Add a claim</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="reply-to-claim-form" class="reply-to-claim-form-container">
    <form method='POST' id='reply-to-claim-form' action='/post_reply'>
        <label for='text-body'>Reply</label>
        <textarea name='text' rows='4' cols='50' placeholder='Enter description: 500 characters or less'></textarea>
        
        <label for='relation'>Select relation:</label>
        <select name='relation'>Select relation
            <option value='clarification'>Clarification</option>
            <option value='support'>Supporting argument</option>
            <option value='counter'>Counterargument</option>
        </select>
        
        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Reply</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="reply-to-reply-form" class="reply-to-reply-form-container">
    <form method='POST' id='reply-to-reply-form' action='/post_reply'>
        <label for='text-body'>Reply</label>
        <textarea name='text' rows='4' cols='50' placeholder='Enter description: 500 characters or less'></textarea>
        
        <label for='relation'>Select relation:</label>
        <select name='relation'>Select relation
            <option value='evidence'>Evidence</option>
            <option value='support'>Support</option>
            <option value='rebuttal'>Rebuttal</option>
        </select>
        
        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Reply</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="{{ url_for('static', filename='forumScript.js') }}"></script>
```

Additionally, here are the buttons I am adding the eventListeners to, for brevity (Note, I am using jinja for some aspects of the web app, these buttons appear conditionally when a user is logged in. I am testing this while logged into my web app.):

```
{%if 'username' in session%}<button type="button" id="addClaim">Add a new claim in this topic</button>
{% endif %}

{% if 'username' in session %}<div class='claim-list-reply'><button type=button id='claim-reply-button'>Reply to claim</button></div> {% endif %}

{% if 'username' in session%}<button type="button" id="addTopic">Add a new topic</button>{% endif %}

{% if 'username' in session %}<button type='button' id='reply-button'>Reply</button>{% endif %}
```

To be clear, these buttons are contained within a

tag (which inside a  tag) but I don't think this should affect anything. I have been wracking my brains over this for hours, looked online, spoken to other friends who code, and I cannot for the life of me diagnose this issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are these wrapped in an onload callback?  you might be trying to setup the listeners too early - before the dom is ready.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: To clarify, you mean as in: function onload(){
the statements
};?

Comment: To update and clarify for anyone viewing this later, I have wrapped the statements in an onload callback (as described in my above comment) and called this in the HTML via <script onload="onloadfunc()" src="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'forumIndexScript.js') }}></script>. Still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your code in one of my own Flask apps to test it out (using different Jinja if-statements that relate to my app) and got it to work. A couple of things I noticed:

- In one of your previous comments you have the filename as `'forumIndexScript.js'` but in your edited question the filename is `'forumScript.js'` so double-check that for accuracy.
- You may also want to check that your file is in the static folder and not nested, or update the script's source if it is. I assume other files load correctly through your url_for('static') path, because you mentioned the CSS file. It is hard to tell if it could be a CSS issue based on what you've provided, such as another file/element/class/style conflict.

By the way, there is also a typo with `.reply-to-**claimform**-container` in your JS code, but that shouldn't affect the others. I hope this helps and if not, you find a solution!

Comment: Thank you for this,  I have tried putting the statements directly into a <script> tag before the closing <body> tag of forumIndex.html to try and get around the linking issue but am still having the same problems (the typos were just me misremembering semantically similar names). The js file was indeed in a static folder along with 2 other css files, and thus far I can't see what conflicts they would have (the css file just sets the display property to none for all the elements I am displaying as flex in the javascript statements). Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using the onload in the script tag, and not the body tag (for example)? You could also do a "window.onload = function onloadfunc() {" in the script itself.

Comment: Honestly, I've tried it every way (just using body tag, using window.onload and using the onload attribute). Still trying to change things around to see if I get any response but as it is I don't get any changes no matter what I do. Thanks for trying!

Comment: If you'd like to share more of your code (css file, any other js, template stuff, etc.) I'd be happy to take a look. Seems like it should be a simple thing to implement, and I wonder what could be causing the problem. P.S. If the buttons appear I doubt it has anything to do with jinja.